# Serial downvoting reversed, but downvoter continues today, any consequence to a serial downvoter or is it just the poster who suffers?

Tags: discussion

I had 7 serial downvotes reversed yesterday - which is fine.

But this morning already I have just received another downvote...

So, my question is does a serial downvoter ever get caught and if they do, what happens?

Comment: single downvote won't get reversed: [a downvote a day keeps the reversal-script away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308502/839601). Double downvote from account previously caught abusing [probably will](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144478/165773): "it is most likely that vote reversal script uses some data about prior abuse..."

Comment: Don't worry about it. The site should award a badge for being serial downvoted. The serial downvoters are pretty much able to do what they want, like setup puppet accounts and write scripts to downvote from the puppet account. There does not seem to be any real interest in stopping them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please see the help page for serial voting:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

> ## What if I think I'm the victim of voting abuse?
>
> If you see very unusual votes being targeted at your account, don't worry about it. You should wait at least 24 hours after noticing before becoming concerned, as the automated system should detect it and reverse it for you. If, after 24 hours, you do not see any fix to your reputation, please contact the team using the "contact us" form located at the bottom of any page.

If this happens more than you believe is reasonable, then please use the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page to have site administrators look into the situation and guide/act as appropriate.

Usually, this is caused by someone being spiteful and the behaviour stops when they find out it isn't really having any effect.

Comment: So, the original question is does anything happen to someone caught committing serial downvoting? as the help page you give does not elucidate.

Comment: Yes, they get their votes handed back to them.  If the behaviour is serial, it'll get addressed by the site admins.  Actual action taken is down to the admin team to decide, usually in the form of education.  Persistent vote abuse may result in suspension.

Comment: Thanks, that is nice to know and your effort is appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: @SolarMike as a side note, as one gains rep (at least here), one tends to gather the infamous "downvote stalkers"... where, no matter if your answer or post is *perfect*, you will see a -1 or -2 now and then... but that is a different situation from serial DVting.